# Order of Complexity

Tags: control-system, state-space, control-theory

Generally, number of independent state variables (order of complexity of a system) is equal to the number of reactive elements in RLC network. But, if capacitor and voltage source loops are present the capacitor contribution goes down, similarly for inductor if a cut set is present. What if, the capacitor and inductor are in series, isn't it enough to specify only the current as state variable since voltage across capacitor can easily be derived?

Comment: Please expand your question to explain it more fully. An example goes a long way for clarification purposes.

Comment: If two inductors are in series, then yes the pair can be represented as a single state since the current in one is the same as the current in the other. But no, not in the case of an LC in series.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the analysis of one exercise can be more useful than many discussions. For example, in the following example an artifice is used to eliminate the derivatives of the input signal from the state equations.
(Click on the image to enlarge.)
[image: Click on the image to enlarge.]